# Pandas: select column with the highest percentage from a frequency table

Tags: pandas

Hi I have a dataframe that I'd like to select the column with the highest percentage from a frequency table.

```
d = {'c1':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 'c2':['Low', 'High', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)
```

It will return a frequency table

```
c1  c2  
a   High     50.0
    Low      50.0
b   High     50.0
    Low      50.0
c   High    100.0
Name: c2, dtype: float64
```

I'd like to print out `c` which has the highest percentage `100.0`

I'm able to use `max()` to print out `100.0` but don't know how to print out `c`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets try reset_index and drop level=1 and then find the maximum index using idxmax

```
dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).idxmax()
```

Comment: good answer. you can drop the `.mul(100)` since it is useless

Comment: awesome thanks. Is there a way to print out "c   High    100.0" ? sorry I should specify it clearer in the question.

Comment: `s = dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100);
s.loc[[s.idxmax()]]`

Comment: Thanks @Quang Hoang , I hadn't noticed the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just do

```
dd.groupby('c1')['c2'].value_counts(normalize=True).idxmax()[0]
Out[102]: 'c'
```